# Caching css, images, javascript files with querystring

Tags: javascript, html, http, caching

In order to force a browser to re-load a new version of css or javascript file, we added a version querystring to the file (e.g. script.js?version=1).

It works fine, however i've noticed that browsers are downloading the file on each refresh, the file is not cached after the first download.

I checked online and i read this book "High Performance Web Sites: Essential Knowledge for Front-End Engineers", they say that the file name should be changed in order to be sure that it will be cached.

My question is does adding a query string prevent the browser from caching files or am i doing something wrong?

Here is the js file response header

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=315360000
Content-Length:516
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Fri, 12 Jun 2015 04:57:51 GMT
ETag:"204"
Expires:Mon, 09 Jun 2025 04:57:51 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 11 Jun 2015 07:34:53 GMT
Server:Apache
```

Comment: A browser can still overload this settings ( in IE : every time I visit the page , in chrome : you also have similar option).

Comment: Thanks @RoyiNamir, do you mean that the default behavior is that the browser will keep a cached copy if the file has a version querystring ??

Comment: No. if the file has version QS ( or even capital letters changed or lowered) - it would still ask again from the server. I'm just saying that even if you request the same  item over and over again and it's the same item , even if cached ,  - you can still make chrome ask it every time a refreshed request. ( by disable cache from the browser)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, it is clear that the browser will ask for the new version, but in my case the browser is not caching the new version it keeps asking for the same version in each page refresh.